# Running Enthought Canopy GUI in a virtual environment

Tags: python, enthought, canopy

This seems like a simple question but I've looked around and cannot find a simple answer.

I've set up a virtual environment in my project folder using `canopy_cli venv <myvenv>`, and now I can run plain python in that environment. How can I run the Canopy GUI using this virtual environment instead?

Answer (score 0):

Your launch script will have to activate that virtual environment:
    $ source myenv/bin/activate
    $ python my_app.py

or the equivalent in Windows:
    C:> /Scripts/activate.bat
    C:> python my_app.py

See [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html) for details.